# Show more button hidden after click

Tags: javascript, toggle

I have a nice script where I show more after clicking a button. This button needs to be hidden after clicking.

This is what I have sofar:

```
 $(function() {
        $(".btn-down").next().hide().append('<a href="javascript:void();" class="btn-up">Show less</a>');

        $(".btn-down").click(function() {
            $(this).next().slideToggle();
        });

        $(".btn-up").click(function() {
            $(this).parent().slideUp();
        });
    });
```

My JSFiddle;
https://jsfiddle.net/w5n7zkwu/5/

An other way is just change the button text after click and put it below the hidden text.

I'm close but don't know how to fix this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the **.hide()** before the **.next()** here

```
$(".btn-down").click(function() {
        $(this).hide().next().slideToggle();
     });
```

Display again your "show more" button with **$(".btn-down").show();** here

```
$(".btn-up").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().slideUp();
    $(".btn-down").show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, its not perfect looking when the button shows again but it works :)
https://jsfiddle.net/w5n7zkwu/20/

Comment: remove the <br> from your HTML for the good looking, you're welcome

Comment: Yea I did on my site. It looks a bit funky when I click on the show less button because of the show more button is being shown without animation. But hey, it works.

Comment: You can add a duration parameter in milliseconds at show() to create an animation, like `$(".btn-down").show(800);` to display the button in 800 milliseconds.